# How to set default value for drop-down/select in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, select, input

I have an arraylist for Strings *eqArray*.

I need to show it in a drop-down list for which I'm using the following in my JSP:

```
<% 

    for(int count=0;count<eqArray.size();count++){ %>
            <option value="<%=eqArray.get(count)%>"><%=eqArray.get(count)%></option>  
     <%} 
%>
```

I have an eqName String which is part of eqArray and should be the selected value by default.

How do I go about it without having to check and set the first option as eqName always?

Comment: You cannot accomplish without checking for the eqName condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<% for(int count=0; count<eqArray.size(); count++){ %>
    <option value="<%= eqArray.get(count) %>" <%= (eqArray.get(count).equals("eqName"))?"selected":"" %> ><%= eqArray.get(count) %></option>  
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the index of eqName element to 0 in the array, or use a conditional Statement.

```
<% 
for(int count=0; count < eqArray.size(); count++){ %>
        <%if(eqArray.equals("eqName"){ %>           
            <option  selected="selected" value="<%=eqArray.get(count)%>"><%=eqArray.get(count)%></option>  
        <%} %> 
        <option value="<%=eqArray.get(count)%>"><%=eqArray.get(count)%></option>  
 <%} %>
```

but use JSTL taglibs instead of using scriptlets.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via JQuery, which IMHO more clean:

```
<select data-selected="${eqName}">
<% 
    for(int count=0;count<eqArray.size();count++){ %>
            <option value="<%=eqArray.get(count)%>"><%=eqArray.get(count)%></option>  
     <%} 
%>
</select>
```

At the end of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("select[data-selected]").each(function() {
      var selected = $(this).data("selected");
      $("select[data-selected='" + selected + "'] option[value='" + selected + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
  })
</script>
```

By this way, you just need include the js at each of your page.

BTW, I recommend you to use JSTL and EL, which is more readable:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<select data-selected="${eqName}">
  <c:forEach items="${eqArray}" var="model">
    <option value="${model}">${model}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement these  in two ways

- By using jsp
- " selected="selected" >
- By Using Javascript  at the end of the select box code

  document.getElementById('selectBoxID').value=""

  instead of selectBoxID id use the select box id